# How to parse MMddyyyy in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have project which contain some historical data of some customers. Data contains some date column which has date like `7272017` (MMddyyyy). I've been able to convert this datetype by using c# utility by using following code.

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact("12022017", "MMddyyyy",
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

But i want to create a utility in javascript to convert this date into ISODate. By using `new Date(07272017)` i am getting default date which is `Thu Jan 01 1970 05:31:17 GMT+0500`. How can i parse format to parse function and convert the date into other format?

This is not the same question as [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

i dont want to convert ANY string .. i want to convert a specific date format which i have done in other language but looking for solution in javascript.

[EDIT]
Moment.js is workable option but i want to convert my existing records stored in mongodb. I know i can't do it with mongo query... i am using nosqlbooster so i have access to shell which can run javascript code.. i am not sure how to link moment.js there?

Comment: The answers to the linked question provide multiple examples of how dates can be parsed, including ones that would work for your specific format.

Comment: updated the question please check if the link fulfill my scenario.

Comment: Everything you need is in the accepted answer to the other question. [Moment](https://momentjs.com/) is the easiest solution because it allows syntax very similar to what you had in C#, but if you can't use it for some reason the solution is to split the string using the appropriate [string methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2) and either reassemble the components into ISO format or use them individually in the constructor to get a `Date` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) I would advise you to do so.

```js
var day = moment("12022017", "MMDDYYYY");

console.log(day);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

For loading external js into mongo shell, read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/)

Comment: This is working.. please see the updated question i want to run in mongo shell i have access to plain javascript not sure how to link moment library there

Comment: You could read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/). Not much of a mongodb expert myself

Comment: i dont think this work with remote links ... i can download the library and provide local path

Comment: yup got it working thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help